# Nexus repository manager to find artifcats doesn´t work

Tags: maven, ant, sonatype

currently I´m working on converting a java project from ant to maven and one step to accomplish this is to find matching artifacts (via SHA1 checksum) in the nexus repository manager, see step 4 here: https://dzone.com/articles/ant-to-maven-conversion-the-painless-method

first I got all the SHA1 signatures of all jar files where I don´t know the specific version (since it´s not my own java project).

then I tried several times to use the following link to search for the artifacts by using the SHA1 checksum as my search query:
https://repository.sonatype.org/

but somehow I get no matching artifacts, no matter what I search.
can anybody help here please?
what am I doing wrong? maybe sonatype repo is not working properly any longer?
or is there any other method to search artifacts via checksum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on https://search.maven.org/, which is the "official" Maven repository.